# How can I make chrome use gmail with mailto: links in Debian?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, email, debian, gmail

I am running Debian Testing and I am trying to make chrome handle links in the (usually opened) gmail, instead of running KMail (which is probably my default mail app atm). I remember that there used to be a way to do it in Iceweasel, does anyone know if this would work in Chrome as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Google Chrome extension [**Mailto: for Gmail™**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dgkkmcknielgdhebimdnfahpipajcpjn) that does what you want.

Have you ever tried it?